# Second hop authentication in vmware vco workflow

Tags: powershell, plugins, vmware, orchestration

I'm writing a flow that suppose to copy files from the Netapp storage to one of my VMs, but i have a problem regarding Second Hop authentication.
I found a way to enable a second hop functionality using powershell  -CredSSP, but that option does not exist in vco powershell  plugin
Are any other way to do that? Or some way to enable cressp in the plugin..
Thanks =)

Answer (score 0):

One workaround that I've used is to deceive the second hop by not using the second hop. First I copy the files that I want each computer to run to the local computer before remoting and running the command. You can accomplish this by using Windows administrative shares. By default, Windows shares their local drives (\\ComputerName\c$ or \\ComputerName\e$). So my script sorta went like this:

```
$Computers = Get-Content Computerlist.txt
$File = \\Server1\applications$\file.exe
foreach($Computer in $Computers){
    copy $file "\\$Computer\c$"
    invoke-command -ComputerName $Computer -ScriptBlock {& 'C:\file.exe'}
    del "\\$Computer\c$\file.exe"
}
```